# как сформировать ссылку по GET запросу?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

Вопрос: как определить в контроллере метод GET для формирования ссылки(и, соответственно, заранее не заданного html) и получения сохраненной сущности из базы для дальнейшего редактирования?
Пишу клон telegra.ph, в этом сервисе при сохранении поста формируется новый URL типа telegra.ph/YY-MM-DD-Title. определил в контроллере метод, который сохраняет модель:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String savedPost(@RequestParam String title,
                      @RequestParam String username,
                      @RequestParam String story){
    Post post = new Post();
    post.setTitle(title);
    post.setUsername(username);
    post.setStory(story);

    postService.add(post);

    return "savedPost";
}
```

в методе add() класса PostService() проставляется текущее время:

```
public void add(Post newPost){
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    newPost.setDate(calendar.getTime());
    postRepository.save(newPost);
}
```

Сама сущность:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_post")
public class Post{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private String username;
    private String story;
    private Date date;
}
```

Вопрос в том, как определить в контроллере метод GET для формирования ссылки(и, соответственно, заранее не заданного html) и получения сохраненной сущности из базы для дальнейшего редактирования?

Comment: пришла идея: в сущность добавить поле URL- если такое решение правильное, то остается вопрос в том, как создавать html.

Comment: Сделайте новый эндпоинт @GetMapping(posts/{id}) и доставайте/возвращайте его по ид.